# Setting up RestKit 0.10.1 for testing while using CocoaPods?

Tags: unit-testing, restkit, cocoapods

I am trying to setup a testing environment for RestKit while using CocoaPods and I can't seem to be able to include RestKit's testing framework.

I followed [Unit Testing with RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Unit-Testing-with-RestKit) but I wasn't able to include any of my podfiles.

Then I found this [article](http://www.irvinruz.com/en/posts/using-cocoapods-to-manage-your-ios-project-dependencies) about setting up CocoaPods with a small section about testing:

> When trying to execute the unit tests of CookPix, I got this issue
>
> LoggerClient.h not found As described above, pod install changes your
>   Xcode project main target (I guess it takes the one named like the
>   project) to base the target configuration on the Pods.xcconfig file.
>   This lets Xcode found the headers of your dependencies and compile
>   your project with the right flags as well.
>
> However it does not change the configuration of all targets and in our
>   case, the unit tests target. To fix that, click on your Xcode project,
>   then again on the Xcode project on the secondary panel, then on the
>   Info tab. Change the "Based on Configuration file" attribute of your
>   unit tests target to Pods. This should fix the dependencies of your
>   unit tests target.

This fixed the issue of including my pod files but I can't get RestKit's test framework installed. The compiler can't find this file because the pod doesn't install it.

```
#import <RestKit/Testing.h>
```

By looking at the CocoaPod spec it looks like it should be included. This is the relevant line in my Podfile.

```
pod 'RestKit', '0.10.1'
```

I also tried:

```
pod 'RestKit/Testing', '0.10.1'
```

With the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't investigated why this works but to include RestKit's testing files you must put

```
pod 'RestKit/Testing', '0.10.1'
```

before

```
pod 'RestKit', '0.10.1'
```

and clear out your pods directory and do a pod install. Or you might be able to skip this step if you are running Cocoapods 0.14.0.rc1 in which case you might be able to use pod update.